# How to install apache superset in the secured servers(Without internet)

Tags: apache-superset

What is the best way of installing the apache superset in the secured server?
I haven't found any answer for it i figured it out with so many trial and error method, So its my small contribution to the community who are facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

Below are the commands to install apache superset in production/Development

**sudo yum install gcc gcc-c++ libffi-devel python-devel python-pip python-wheel openssl-devel cyrus-sasl-devel openldap-devel**

**sudo yum install python3**

**sudo yum install python3-devel**

Since server has no internet you need to download it from below python community in your local system and transfer it to the server
Download all dependencies from :- https://pypi.org/simple/

To untar :- **tar -xvf package.tar**

Go to untared folder and run below command
**sudo python3.x setup.py install** x=your python version

If the package is of wheel extension i.e .whl run below command
**sudo python3.6 -m pip install packagename.whl**

After installing all the dependencies run below command

**fabmanager create-admin --app superset**

**superset db upgrade**

**superset init**

**superset run -p port --with-threads --reload --debugger** - For development

**gunicorn -b IP:port superset:app** --For production use

Hope this will help someone who is facing issue,
If there is any changes or i missed please add